# Respect BIOS-specified CPU speed without kernel patches, etc. in 14.04

Tags: kernel, cpu, overheating

I've got a machine running "in the wild" in a very hot environment running an AMD chip which is overheating. I don't have physical access to the machine, but I have had someone change the CPU clock speed in the BIOS for me.

Unfortunately, the OS doesn't respect this and throttles the CPU back up to full speed when needed.

I cannot install any software through apt-get nor can I upload any software to the machine; I need to work with the system in its current state due to security limitations.

What I need to do is either (1) lock the machine in its lowest CPU speed or (2) have it respect the BIOS-specified CPU speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `cpupower` command available *(part of [`linux-tools-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-tools-common) package, I think included by default)*, you can use a powersaving CPU governor to limit the speed - you can list the available governors with:

```
cpupower frequency-info --governors
```

*Example output:*

```
analyzing CPU 0:
conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance
```

And set it with this (as root):

```
cpupower frequency-set -g GOVERNOR
```

e.g.

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -g conservative
```

You can then view the current state by running `sudo cpupower frequency-info` - example output:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.50 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.50 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1000 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, userspace, powersave, ondemand, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.50 GHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
2900 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
2900 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
2900 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
3100 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Documentation on what each governor does cna be found [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt?id=HEAD) - here is a summary (you probably want the powersave one):

> ### 2.1 Performance
>
> The CPUfreq governor "performance" sets the CPU statically to the
>   highest frequency within the borders of scaling_min_freq and
>   scaling_max_freq.
>
> ### 2.2 Powersave
>
> The CPUfreq governor "powersave" sets the CPU statically to the lowest
>   frequency within the borders of scaling_min_freq and scaling_max_freq.
>
> ### 2.3 Userspace
>
> The CPUfreq governor "userspace" allows the user, or any userspace
>   program running with UID "root", to set the CPU to a specific
>   frequency by making a sysfs file "scaling_setspeed" available in the
>   CPU-device directory.
>
> ### 2.4 Ondemand
>
> The CPUfreq governor "ondemand" sets the CPU depending on the current
>   usage. To do this the CPU must have the capability to switch the
>   frequency very quickly. ...
>
> ### 2.5 Conservative
>
> The CPUfreq governor "conservative", much like the "ondemand"
>   governor, sets the CPU depending on the current usage.  It differs in
>   behaviour in that it gracefully increases and decreases the CPU speed
>   rather than jumping to max speed the moment there is any load on the
>   CPU.  This behaviour more suitable in a battery powered environment. ...

This governors can be set to be used fairly easily (there's even [a Unity extension](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/indicator-cpufreq/) that can be used so it can be done from a desktop user's panel), and can save a fair amount of power when used (extra hour/half hour batter life for a laptop, etc)

Comment: The linux-tools-common package was not installed, but it turns out that the package was available through the private mirror that the machine was configured to use. Thanks!